# Push down menu links not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, menu

I have a simple push down menu but the link close the menu when you click on them - they highlight when you navigate over them and they also highlight when you click but it the menu just closes without moving to the selected page?

```
#nav-mobile {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 12px;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 33px;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 0.9em;
     background: none;  
}

#nav-mobile, #nav-mobile ul, #nav-mobile li {
    position: relative; 
      background: none;  
}
#nav-mobile ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
      background: none;  
}
#nav-mobile ul li {
    width: 100%;
    display: block; 
    padding: 13px 0 13px 0;
    margin: 0;
      background: none;  
}
#nav-mobile ul a:hover {
    background: none;   
}
#nav-mobile ul li:hover {
    background: none;
}

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#nav-mobile ul').hide();
    $('#nav-mobile').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#nav-mobile ul').slideToggle();
    });
});
</script>

  <div id="nav-mobile">
    <a href="#">Menu</a>
<ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="whyus.html">Why us?</a></li>
        <li><a href="faqs.html">FAQs</a></li>
        <li><a href="careers.html">Career</a></li>
        <li id="last-child"><a href="contactus.html">Contact us</a></li>
        <li id="last-child"><a href="#">Portal</a></li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` will prevent the browser from following the url in the href tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e.preventDefault();` 
prevents the Linking - remove it!

the click event of the container will always fire first - so slide toggle might be a problem as well!